# How to get all farest points to create a polygon or (a line polygon) include all points

Tags: math, computer-vision, geometry, opencv, python

Well I have a list of point (x,y). I need to select out all points that could include all inside points.

List of point on (x,y) plane.

[image: List of points]

I select out all farest point to create a polygon (a poly line) that include all points

[image]

Well this is actually the problem of math not coding. Since I am bad at it so it would be nice if you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is called [**convex hull**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)

OpenCV [has functio](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga014b28e56cb8854c0de4a211cb2be656)n for building it

If you need to implement convex hull "by hands" - look at [the list of corresponding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms)